# Migrating ASP.NET 2005 VB.NET to ASP.NET 2010 VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to migrate ASP.NET 2005/VB.NET 2005 code to ASP.NET 2010/VB2010.

After I drag and dropped all the files of 2005 to 2010, lots of error. How to convert ASP.NET 2005 application to ASP.NET 2010.

I knew that in 2010 there are 3 files generated when creating a page. 
.vb
.vb.designer
.aspx

in 2005 htere are only 2 files. 
.vb
.aspx

Is there a fastest way to migrate everything as fast as drag and drop?

Comment: There is no need to drag and drop anything.  You simply open the existing project in VS 2010.

Comment: Exactly what did you drag and drop? From where to where? Does you 2005 site have a .vbproj file in it?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: that only works if there _is_ a project.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, the question does say "ASP.NET 2005 application", which would suggest that there is.  If it's just a web site, which I didn't really think about because I don't use them, then that would be another matter.  It is plausible that the OP used "application" as a lay term rather than precise programming term.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: the fact that he uses the word "application" means nothing. People refer to "PHP applications". That doesn't mean it's using a Web Application Project.

Comment: @John Saunders  I dragged and dropped only the files so as the reference DLL's From 2005 to 2010. But error on all controls and classes occured. Does that have something to do with the Namespace? I tried to change the namespace but still error. I dont have the .vsproj so I created a new project in VS 2010 then drag and dropped everything there.

Comment: Did your site have a .vbproj file in it?

Comment: @John Saunders.. I have none, all i have are the .aspx and the code behind which is .vb

Comment: Then your problem is that you have a web site "project", which is not really a project. Google for "convert web site project to web application project". You're probably better off converting it first to a VS2005 web application project, then just open the .vbproj file with VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for the advice John Sanders, I got this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx and I think this is the solution to my problem. Thanks again.